# Why am I getting an Invalid typecast error from this code?

Tags: linux, delphi

```pascal
function FileSize64(var F : File): Int64;
var
  ph :_stat;
  pl:longword;
begin
  pl := fstat(TFileRec(f).Handle, ph);
  if (pl = $ffffffff) and (GetLastError <> 0) then
    CreateIOException(GetLastError, 'FileSize64', f, false);
  FileSize64 := Int64(ph) shl 32 + pl;
end;
```

I am getting an error:

> E2089 Invalid typecast

Comment: Where (in your code)?

Comment: You don't need to create a new user account.

Comment: Where does this code come from? Did you write it? Or did you take it from somewhere else? I suspect the latter and that you don't really understand it. Also, why are you using legacy IO? And finally what is your question? You have to ask a question. What is it?

Comment: It seems that you want to get the file size, Check Indy's function `FileSizeByName` in `IdGlobalProtocols` unit.

Comment: `fstat()` returns an `Integer` not a `LongWord`. And the return value is not a byte size. And you don't need to check `GetLastError()` before raising the exception: `if fstat(...) < 0 then CreateIOException(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
  uses
    Posix.SysStat;

  function FileSize64(var F: File): Int64;
  var
    ph :_stat;
  begin
    if fstat(TFileRec(F).Handle, ph) <> 0 then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    result := ph.st_size;
  end;
```

Hint: In the next question, please inform which units are referenced in the uses list.